# How can I fix this 'Unable to connect to the Parse API' error

Tags: node.js, rest, runtime, moralis

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
```

Error: XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API"

Call Stack
handleError
node_modules\moralis\lib\browser\RESTController.js (445:0)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your server is active/online in the admin dashboard.